# how to disable EL expression for a few lines in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

In some JSP pages, I want to the page display

```
<h4>${id}</h4>
```

However, EL will try to evaluate "id" variable and leave it to blank(not find the variable) or the actual value.

```
 <h4>123</h4>
```

I know there is a

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

but this will disable EL for the whole JSP page.

Is there any way to disable EL just for a few lines?

Thanks guys, I also write a post about this.
http://www.ke-cai.net/2010/12/jquery-template-markup-and-jsp.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [JSP 2.0 spec](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr152/index.html):

Quoting in EL Expressions

- There is no special quoting mechanism within EL expressions; use a literal 
  `'${'` if the literal `${` is desired and expressions are enabled for the page. For 
  example, the evaluation of `${'${'}` is `'${'`. Note that `${'}'}` is legal, and simply 
  evaluates to `'}'`.

So in your case, instead of:

```
<h4>${id}</h4>
```

do this:

```
<h4>${'${'}id}</h4>
```

It certainly doesn't look pretty but it's what the Java Community Process settled on.

Comment: I think you mean `${'${id}'}` in your last example.

Comment: Ah, I see what you were doing now.

Answer (score 5):

Backslash is the easiest.

```
<h4>\${id}</h4>
```

**Edit:** I have used this method in conjunction with the offical jQuery Template plugin which has variables of the same syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Represent `$` as a HTML/XML entity.

```
<h1>&#36;{id}</h1>
```